# OpenSSL ChangeCipherSpec vulnerability - ubuntu solution

Tags: ubuntu, openssl

I checked a site with this [tool](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest) and the result came back that " This server is vulnerable to the OpenSSL CCS vulnerability (CVE-2014-0224) and exploitable."

I searched around and found that for not being vulnerable the version must be higher than this output:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
built on: Mon Jun 2 19:37:18 UTC 2014
```

My current version is

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
built on: Fri May  2 20:25:02 UTC 2014
```

I tried couple ways to upgrade my openssl like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429385/upgrade-openssl-on-ubuntu-12-04) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/587528/how-to-upgrade-openssl-on-ubuntu-server-12-04-lts-heartbleed) but I still get the same version. For example when I execute the `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` I get this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

The first time I run this command, packages were installed and I did reboot my machine with `sudo reboot`.

Any clue how can I update my openSSL to avoid this vulnerability? Anything else I might be missing?

Comment: Before doing the apt-get dist-upgrade, I assume you also did an apt-get update? Also, given that Ubuntu (and many other Linux distributions) backports security fixes you will need to provide the full package version. In Debian/Ubuntu you can get that information by running apt-cache policy openssl.

Comment: Wait a second here, OpenSSL 1.0.1c? Any chance that you running Ubuntu 12.10? That Ubuntu version is no longer supported, hence no recent security fixes.

Comment: yes I am running 12.10 :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, as suggested in the question comments your problem is that you are running Ubuntu 12.10, which stoped being supported earlier this year, just about a month before the OpenSSL CCS issue was published. Hence, there aren't any good OpenSSL versions for Ubuntu 12.10, and there won't be.

Getting an openssl/libssl packages from a newer Ubuntu might not be trivial, given that other packages you have installed might depend on a specific openssl version. Seem to recall libssl being fairly version critical when compiled against.

While there are things you could do, such as backporting the fix yourself (non-trivial) you really need to upgrade to a supported version of Ubuntu, given all other potential security issues in other packages. Especially since you appear to be running a web server, which usually has a fairly large attack surface.

For a server you usually want to go with a LTS version of Ubuntu. Especially these days, with the new non-LTS versions only being supported nine months, and the LTS versions getting five years of supported. Current LTS versions being Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

The openssl library may be up-to-date but already started software may be using the old version.

After each shared library update, every software using it should be restarted to use the new version.

The package `debian-goodies` contains a script : `checkrestart` that will list the software running with old versions of updated libraries and suggest the restart of affected daemons.

Comment: thank you for posting. that's what I got: Found 0 processes using old versions of upgraded files